# Making a jQuery plugin to feed Tumblr to site

Tags: jquery, json, tumblr

I have some experience with PHP and a little with JS but I'm far from anything proficient. I'm trying to make a jQuery plugin for my site that I can call in my HTML via something like this:

```
$('.new').tumble({username: "tylor", count: 9});
```

Which would basically put the Tumblr list the code should make into the DIV with class 'new' in this case. Here is my code so far; the problem seems to be how to get it to pick up class/id from the original call (in the HTML) and use that in the jQuery.

Here's the code so far:

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.tumble = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
      username: null,                           // [string or array] required to get url for tumblr account
      count: 3,                                 // [integer]  how many posts to display?
    }, options);

    //url construction
    var url = "http://" + settings.username + ".tumblr.com";
    var jsonurl = url + "/api/read/json?num=" + settings.count + "&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data.posts, function(id, url) { // Goes over each post in the JSON document retrieved from data URL
        var url = this.url; // Just assigns a variable to the url to avoid constantly writing "this.whatever" 
        var photourl = this['photo-url-250']; // photo-url-xxx needs to be called this way due to integers in the name
        items.push('<li><a href="' + url + '">' + photourl + '</a></li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>', { // Creates an empty list
        html: items.join('') // Takes the values in the item array and puts 'em together
      }).appendTo('.new'); // I don't want this to have the class set in the jQuery itself
    }); //end json
  };

})( jQuery );
```

Any help you can lend would be wonderful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you still need help with this but I built a little plugin last week which fits your needs. Feel free to use it, the info's on my blog http://jimukjxb.tumblr.com/ . It uses  V2 of the tumblr API though. The code is similar to what you have written already but im using Ajax calls. Hope its useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `.appendTo(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec:

"There's no need to do $(this) because
 "this" is already a jquery object"

So try saving that last bit to a var and appending it via `this.append(theVar);`

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: I'm really quite new to jQuery and JS programming in general. Would you be able to throw that into the code where it should go? That'd be very helpful

Comment: Try this:
`var theModule = $('<ul/>', { html: items.join('') }).html();`
`this.append(theModule);`

Comment: Seamus, I tried your code and it doesn't seem to be working either. I'm not really sure why this script isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

How Seamus James said, you should use this instead of $(this) but, being inside the getJson function you can't access this directly... so save in a var this ... like:
 var $container = this;

at the begining  and then you can use $container as this inside the function... I pass my code, that's working:

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.tumble = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
      username: null,                           // [string or array] required to get url for
      tumblr account
      count: 3,                                 // [integer]  how many posts to display?
    }, options);

    var $container = this;
    //url construction
    var url = "http://" + settings.username + ".tumblr.com";
    var jsonurl = url + "/api/read/json?num=" + settings.count + "&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(jsonurl, function(data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data.posts, function(id, url) { // Goes over each post in the JSON document retrieved from data URL
      var url = this.url; // Just assigns a variable to the url to avoid constantly writing "this.whatever" 
      var photourl = this['photo-url-250']; // photo-url-xxx needs to be called this way due to integers in the name
      items.push('<li><a href="' + url + '">' + photourl + '</a></li>');
    });

    var htmlString = "<ul>"+items.join(' ')+"</ul>";
    $container.html(htmlString);
    //$('<ul/>', { // Creates an empty list
    // html: items.join('') // Takes the values in the item array and puts 'em together
    //}).appendTo('.new'); // I don't want this to have the class set in the jQuery itself
    }); //end json
  };
})( jQuery );
```